# How to flatten liquibase migrations into a schema init file?

Tags: sql, spring, liquibase

In our current project we are using liquibase to manage DB migrations.
Our migrations are `*.sql` files. We have currently 156 such migrations in master.

Our project is a spring boot application, and the DB used is PostgreSQL 9.6.

To make DB init faster when booting new environments (for testings and for development) we would like to flatten all this migrations into one. Is there an automatic way to do that in liquibase? Or are we bound to export the current schema into a file and reset changelogs manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate a changelog from an existing database [as described in the manual](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/generating_changelogs.html)

Once you have initialized a database to the state you want, you can run Liquibase again using `generateChangeLog` as the parameter:

```
liquibase --changeLogFile=complete_migration.postgresql.sql
          --driver=org.postgresql.Driver 
          --classpath=postgresql-42.2.8.jar 
          --url=... 
          --username=... 
          --password=...   generateChangeLog
```

This will generate a file named `complete_migration.postgresql.sql` that represents the current state of the database.

Note that I formatted the command on multiple lines, how exactly you run a multi-line command depends on the operating system you are using.

Comment: We have 41 changelog files. It takes about 10 seconds to run through them all. That's not long in prod, but it slows testing in dev mode against in-memory DB. Perhaps better to regenerate the schema into a single file regularly (perhaps every release).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like it might be beneficial to profile your current DB init process and see where the time is coming from. I don't think that taking your 156 sql files and converting them into a single sql file will help much - the overhead of just reading the different files is not likely the 'longest pole in the tent'.

Comment: This is a good point. I will check.
Another worry is that some of my colleagues have been given very pour working machines and we have noticed that applying all migrations (vs just applying a schema gotten from pg_dump) was slower.
Thanks for this idea.